# How to unstack a crosstable as fast as possible

Tags: python, pandas

Here's my dataset:

```
Id     Column_A    Column_B
1             1           0
2             1           1
3             0           1
4             0           0
```

Here's my expected output:

```
Id     Column
1      Column_A
2      Column_B
2      Column_B
3      Column_C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) by condition - here not equal `0` and remove helper column `value`:

```
df = df.melt('Id', var_name='Column').query('value != 0').drop('value',1)
print (df)
   Id    Column
0   1  Column_A
1   2  Column_A
5   2  Column_B
6   3  Column_B
```